# regex alphanumeric, but when it gets a numeric, then only numeric

Tags: regex, numeric, alphanumeric

I need to validate an input that must start with an alpha, and then it can be alphanumeric, but once numeric; it must be numeric to the end of the string.

```
[a-z][a-z,0-9]{1,5}
```

This does only part of the job. So it validates correctly for

```
a1
abc12
ab123
```

but I do not want

```
a1b2c1
```

so onces it gets a numeric, the rest must be numeric.

Comment: [a-z][a-z]{1,5}[0-9]{1,5}. Not exactly what you want but you can try

Comment: Do you really want a comma in your character class?

Comment: Is the string required to be 2 to 6 characters long?

Comment: Yes, the string is to be 2 to 6 characters, so 'a1' is valid so is 'ab1234'; but not a12b2, so the instance when a numeric appears, the the rest (if any must be a numeric)

Comment: The comma was an error, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`^(?=.{2,6}$)([a-z]+[0-9]*)$`

First check for 2-6 characters from beginning to end of line.  It doesn't even matter what characters they are - you are just checking for length.

Then, 1 or more letters followed by any number of numbers.  Since you already checked for 2-6 characters only you don't really care how many letters are followed by how many numbers.  At first, I thought it would be much more complicated to list all the possibilities but the positive lookahead does alot of the work

See https://regex101.com/r/HYQIf6/5

Answer (score 0):

This should work for a string of any length:

```
^[a-z]+([a-z]*|\d*)$
```

This will return true if the string:

- starts with one or more letters from a to z
- followed by zero or more: letters or numbers until the end

See the matches at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/v4grsJ/3/)

Edit:

This works as well:

```
^[a-z]+\d*$
```

See new [regex](https://regex101.com/r/v4grsJ/4)

Comment: From the comment by the OP: "Yes, the string is to be 2 to 6 characters".

Comment: @Mark, Sure, but since it works for strings with any number of characters it also works for 2 to 6 characters. You can test the length separately. And being a simple regex it is easy to maintain in case the rules change. Also, it doesn't have any lookahead.

Comment: If you are using a separate check for length, just use `^([a-z]+[0-9]*)$`.